# Create dynamic Header that is aware of the amount of PDFs created in one 'addPage` operation

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have an application that prints several dynamic HTML Pages to PDF.
Usually

```
foreach($html as $htm) {
  $pdf->AddPage();
  $pdf->writeHTML($htm,true,0,true,0);
}
```

Every html Page starts with an Header, which it takes directly from the HTML Template, which denotes the number of the page, i.e. `Page 1` for the first page, `Page 2` for the second ...

Usually, one HTML Page consists of exactly one PDF, but sometimes the number of HTML Pages exceeds.

In this case, I want the header to print `Page 1 of 1` for the first subpage of the first page, `Page 2 of 2` for the second one....

The problem is, it seems, that I cannot use the header of the Template Page since it must now whether there will be several PDFs printed from it.

How do I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

The `getAliasNbPages` method returns a token that TCPDF later updates with the actual number of pages.

Similarly, the `getAliasNumPage` method will return an alias string for the current page number.

For example, your Header could contain something like:

```
$pdf->writeHTML('Page '. $pdf->getAliasNumPage() . ' of ' . $pdf->getAliasNbPages());
```